# SSL client/server mutual authentication

Tags: c#, authentication, ssl, client

Hello I am trying to do in C# an ssl client/server communication with mutual authentication using server and client certificate. A managed to do the ssl communication only using server certificate, where on the client side I use sth like that:

```
TcpClient client = new TcpClient(machineName, port);
//Create an SSL stream that will close the client's stream.
   SslStream sslStream = new SslStream(
   client.GetStream(),
   false,
   new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(ValidateServerCertificate),
   null
   );
try
{
    // The server name must match the name on the server certificate.
    sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(serverName);
}
catch (AuthenticationException e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Exception: {0}", e.Message);
    if (e.InnerException != null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Inner exception: {0}", e.InnerException.Message);
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Authentication failed - closing the connection.");
    client.Close();
    return;
}
```

I assume I would need to use

```
AuthenticateAsClient(string targetHost, X509CertificateCollection clientCertificates, SslProtocols enabledSslProtocols, bool checkCertificateRevocation)
```

method, am I corrent? Could anyone please show me how to use it with all things around?Even on the server side, or point me to a basic example?

Thank you a lot.

Comment: Can I ask why you haven't tried to use the WCF framework? They have options for mutual authentication and do a lot of heavy lifting for you. [WCF documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa663324)

Answer (score 6):

```
static void HTTPSClient()
{
    try
    {
        string message = "GET / HTTP/1.0\r\nHost: host.com\r\n\r\n";

        byte[] data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);

        string server = "host.com";
        int nPort = 443;
        TcpClient client = new TcpClient(server, nPort);

        X509Certificate2Collection cCollection = new X509Certificate2Collection();
        cCollection.Add(new X509Certificate2("cert.pfx", "password"));


        using (SslStream sslStream = new SslStream(client.GetStream(), false, new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(ValidateServerCertificate), null))
        {
            // Add a client certificate to the ssl connection
            sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(server, cCollection, System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols.Default, true);

            sslStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);

            data = new Byte[8192];
            int bytes = 0;
            string responseData = "";

            do
            {
                bytes = sslStream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
                if (bytes > 0)
                {
                    responseData += System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, bytes);
                }
            }
            while (bytes > 0);

            Console.WriteLine("Response: " + responseData);
        }

        // Disconnect and close the client
        client.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error: " + ex.ToString());
    }
}

public static bool ValidateServerCertificate(object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
{
    if (sslPolicyErrors == SslPolicyErrors.None)
        return true;

    Console.WriteLine("Certificate error: {0}", sslPolicyErrors);

    // Do not allow this client to communicate with unauthenticated servers.
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! It's always better to provide a short description for a sample code to improve the post accuracy :)

Answer (score 2):

1. You need a x509 self certificate, to create it simple, download [pluralsight self cert](http://www.pluralsight.com/community/cfs-file.ashx/__key/CommunityServer.Blogs.Components.WeblogFiles/keith.SampleCode/SelfCert.zip)
2. Generate certificate as in  [image](http://img832.imageshack.us/img832/9964/certificatei.png)
3. Create new web site, there choose wcf service.
4. Add in solution new console application, to test our service.
5. In web.config of service put configuration:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
   <behaviors>
       <serviceBehaviors>
           <behavior name="ServiceCredentialsBehavior">
               <serviceCredentials>
                   <serviceCertificate findValue="cn=cool" storeName="TrustedPeople" storeLocation="CurrentUser" />
               </serviceCredentials>
               <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
           </behavior>
       </serviceBehaviors>
   </behaviors>
   <services>
       <service behaviorConfiguration="ServiceCredentialsBehavior" name="Service">
           <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="MessageAndUserName" name="SecuredByTransportEndpoint" contract="IService"/>
       </service>
   </services>
   <bindings>
       <wsHttpBinding>
           <binding name="MessageAndUserName">
               <security mode="Message">
                   <message clientCredentialType="UserName"/>
               </security>
           </binding>
       </wsHttpBinding>
   </bindings>
   <client/>
   ```
6. In Service class, delete existing methods and add:

   public string TestAccess()
   {
    return OperationContext.Current.ServiceSecurityContext.PrimaryIdentity.Name;
   }
7. in IService delete Data Contract, delete operation contracts and add new operation contract:

   [OperationContract]
   public string TestAccess();
8. Run service and add service reference in client application to our service
9. **Client config:**

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <configuration>
      <system.serviceModel>
     <behaviors>
       <endpointBehaviors>
           <behavior name="LocalCertValidation">
               <clientCredentials>
                   <serviceCertificate>
                       <authentication certificateValidationMode="PeerTrust" trustedStoreLocation="CurrentUser" />
                   </serviceCertificate>
               </clientCredentials>
           </behavior>
       </endpointBehaviors>
   </behaviors>
   <bindings>
       <wsHttpBinding>
           <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IService" >
               <security mode="Message">
                   <message clientCredentialType="UserName" />
               </security>
           </binding>
       </wsHttpBinding>
   </bindings>
   <client>
       <endpoint address="your service addresss"
                 binding="wsHttpBinding"
                 bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IService"
                 contract="ServiceReference1.IService"
                 name="WSHttpBinding_IService" behaviorConfiguration="LocalCertValidation">
           <identity>
               <dns value ="cool" />
           </identity>
       </endpoint>
   </client>
   ```
10. Client code:

    ServiceClient client = new ServiceClient();
    client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "Your windows user";
    client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "Your windows user password";
    Console.WriteLine(client.TestAccess());
    Console.ReadLine();
11. if you dont want to use windows login/password you have to create a custom user/passwd validator [->msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa702565.aspx): 

    **Regards,**
    **Sergiu.**

Comment: Voted down because the question didn't mention about WCF, and this answer is all about WCF.